# Hide JqueryUI dialog window on mobile browsers

Tags: css, jquery-ui, media-queries

I have a jqueryUI dialog window that opens at pageload.  Very simple, very easy:

```
<script>
$(function() {
  $( "#dialog-modal" ).dialog({
    dialogClass: 'fixed-dialog',
    resizable: false,
    width: 580,
    top: 200,
    modal: true
  });
});
</script>

<div class="dialog-wrapper"></div>

<script>
$('.dialog-wrapper')
  .html('<div id="dialog-modal" class="dialog-right bigdialog"    title="Click to close"><a href="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_s-xclick&hosted_button_id=YNQGF43QJK2VG" target="_blank"><img class="overlay-image" src="/images/digger-24k-anim.gif"></a></div>');
</script>
```

The problem is, I'd like to hide this on mobile browsers, but it's not working at all.  Any attempts to use a css media query to display: none on certain monitor resolutions isn't getting picked up, as the element style on jquery-ui is display: block;

Any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the size of the screen. If it less than minimum size, skip dialog.

```
if($(window).height() >= miniumHeight && $(window).width() >= minimumWidth) {
    /*Show Dialog Box*/
} else {
    /*Do Something Else*/
}
```

Another way would be the css `visibility: hidden;`